# Is it possible to bind to pouchdb be with angler2

Tags: angular, pouchdb

One of the great things in angular 2  is the 2 way binding. is it possible to bind directly to a pouchdb doc from angular 2 form?

regards

Sean

Answer (score 1):

Unless PouchDB provides Angular2 directives/pipes, then no.

Comment: If they use custom tags and properties and event it can still work. Angular2 works fine with Polymer for example.